# user_delete_account_end hook doesn't appear to be working

Tags: solspace-user, hook, users

*Firstly apologies for my explanation and terminology, this is a relatively new area for me.*

I've built an extension which uses three hooks:

- user_register_end
- user_edit_end
- user_delete_account_end

The first two are working correctly however the last one doesn't appear to be. The hook is referenced in Solspace User in file mod.user.php as is the `user_register_end` one.

Here are the two hook initiations:

```
//Register user hook (working)
if (ee()->extensions->active_hook('user_register_end') === TRUE)
{
    $edata = ee()->extensions->universal_call('user_register_end', $this, $member_id);
    if (ee()->extensions->end_script === TRUE) return;
}

//Delete user hook (not working)
if (ee()->extensions->active_hook('user_delete_account_end') === TRUE)
{
    $edata = ee()->extensions->universal_call('user_delete_account_end', $this);
    if (ee()->extensions->end_script === TRUE) return;
}
```

And here is my code for both hooks:

```
//Hook array used to populate the extensions table
$hooks = array(
    'user_register_end' => 'new_client_check',
    'user_edit_end' => 'upd_client_check',
    'user_delete_account_end' => 'del_client_check'
);

function upd_client_check($member_id, $user_object, $cfields) {
    //Function code
}

function del_client_check($member_data) {
    return('working');
    die;
}
```

During my tests I've been printing out comments or data and killing the function so it stops right away and this has been working fine so far. Now though when I delete a member I'm just shown the successful delete message so the hook isn't being noticed.

I can confirm that all the hooks and methods are in the database correctly.
[image: Image of extensions table hooks and methods]

Can anyone help at all? And if you need to me explain in more detail I'll try my best.

**Edit** I am using this extension with the Solspace User delete form.

Thank you.

Comment: You're using `return` before `die`, which means your PHP script will see `return` then stop, and never see the `die` command. Try `echo 'working'; die();` or even simply `die('working');`

Comment: Aha! Thank you very much for that, it's working as intended now. Always nice to learn something new too.

Comment: Great! I posted the above as a solution. Feel free to mark it as the solution. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using `return` before `die`, which means your PHP script will see `return` then stop, and never see the `die` command. Try `echo 'working'; die();` or even simply `die('working');`

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [change log for when that hook was added](http://www.solspace.com/docs/user/change_log/#v3.2.3), it states:

> Added a "user_delete_account_end" hook to the end of the delete_account function for the Delete_form tag

So this tells me that this hook only fires when an account is deleted using User's own [delete_form](http://www.solspace.com/docs/user/delete_form/) tag.

To hook into member deletion via the control panel, you'll want to use EE's own [cp_members_member_delete_end](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/extension_hooks/cp/members/index.html#cp-members-member-delete-end) hook.

Comment: Sorry, I should've mentioned that this is using the Solspace User delete form. I'll add this to my question. Thanks for the prompt response though.